# Javascript order of evaluation

Tags: javascript, operator-precedence

Came across this JS snippet, and I honestly have NO idea of what order things are being evaluated in...
Any ideas? Parentheses would be helpful...

```
return point[0] >= -width / 2 - allowance &&
       point[0] <= width / 2 + allowance && 
       point[1] >= -height / 2 - allowance && 
       point[1] <= height / 2 + allowance;
```

Comment: FWIW: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operator_Precedence

Comment: Now that it's formatted, it makes more sense! It originally looked like this, no newlines: return point[0] >= -width / 2 - allowance && point[0] <= width / 2 + allowance && point[1] >= -height / 2 - allowance && point[1] <= height / 2 + allowance;

Comment: It might help future readers if you relate the function of this code now that you have deciphered the order of evaluation.

Comment: @watsgoingon: which just goes to show, parentheses aren't the only (or even necessarily the best) way to help readers visualize your expressions.

Answer (score 3):

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operator_Precedence

The relavant operators go in this order: unary negation, division, addition/subtraction, relational (>=, <=), logical and.

```
return (point[0] >= ((-width / 2) - allowance))
    && (point[0] <= ((width / 2) + allowance))
    && (point[1] >= ((-height / 2) - allowance))
    && (point[1] <= ((height / 2) + allowance))
```

Answer (score 2):

Equivalent to:

```
return
    (point[0] >= ((-width  / 2) - allowance))
 && (point[0] <= (( width  / 2) + allowance))
 && (point[1] >= ((-height / 2) - allowance))
 && (point[1] <= (( height / 2) + allowance));
```

Comment: What about this: `-width / 2 - allowance`? The `/` operator has precedence over the second `-`

Comment: This will trigger a Javascript semicolon insertion bug unless you start your expression on the same line as the return statement.

Answer (score 2):

check this

```
function bob(n){
  alert(n);
  return n;
}

return bob(1) >= bob(2) / bob(3) - bob(4) &&
       bob(5) <= bob(6) / bob97) + bob(8) && 
       bob(9) >= bob(10) / bob(11) - bob(12) && 
       bob(13) <= bob(14) / bob(15) + bob(16);
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding paratheses and some indentation should make it clearer:

```
return 
  point[0] >= (-width / 2) - allowance 
    && 
  point[0] <= (width / 2) + allowance 
    && 
  point[1] >= (-height / 2) - allowance 
    && 
  point[1] <= (height / 2) + allowance;
```

Answer (score 0):

`return (point[0]) >= (-width / 2 - allowance) && (point[0] <= width / 2 + allowance) && (point[1] >= -height / 2 - allowance) && (point[1]) <= (height / 2 + allowance);`